# Several variants in a page

Tags: 7, panels

Is it possible to use several variants in a page?
In the page I made only one variant is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first variant that "passes" will be the one that is shown.

So if the first (top) variant does not have any conditions limiting when it is displayed, it will **always** be the one that is shown.